# Getting top 10 most popular within an array column using SQL UNNEST

Tags: sql, unnest

I am working with a sample data set which gives the following result:
[image]

Continuing to work, I am now trying to get the top 10 Production Companies (based on "production_companies" field) that made the most number of movies in the most popular genre for a year.

The output
Rank | Production Company | Popular Genre | Movie Count

I thought breaking this down to getting the most popular genre for the year would be the 1st step with the following query:

```
select
    genres.name AS _genre,    
FROM
    commons.movies m,
    UNNEST(m.genres) as genres
WHERE
    SUBSTR(m.release_date, 1, 4) = '2008'
GROUP BY
    genres.name
ORDER BY
    COUNT(genres.name) DESC
LIMIT
    1
```

I have now go the output as 'Drama' being the most popular genre for the year 2008.

Answering the question to get the most popular prod company and their count has been a bit challenging and failing several times.

I have after several tries got to:

```
select
    o_prd_cmp.name,
    o_mov.title
from
    commons.movies o_mov,
    unnest(o_mov.genres) as o_gnr,
    UNNEST(o_mov.production_companies) AS o_prd_cmp
where
    SUBSTR(o_mov.release_date, 1, 4) = '2008'
    AND o_gnr.name = (
        select
            genres.name AS _genre,
        FROM
            commons.movies m,
            UNNEST(m.genres) as genres
        WHERE
            SUBSTR(m.release_date, 1, 4) = '2008'
        GROUP BY
            genres.name
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(genres.name) DESC
        LIMIT
            1
    )
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Do you store dates as character data?!? Use proper date data type instead.

Comment: I think it is Postgres. It is a sample dataset provided, unfortunately date is a string, so I am using SUBSTR to get the year. The issue is with the 'prod_companies'. Not the best data set to work with but its a learning.

Comment: What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: It gives me an error. I am running on rockset platform